# Creating a stacked bar plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a stacked bar plot to display for each column x1-4 how many of the total 14 observations are -1 and how many are 1.
I want to get them all on the same graph - 1 bar for each column.
The numbers can be treated as factors.

The data :

```
    x1   x2     x3    x4
1   -1    1     1      1
2   -1    1     1     -1
3   -1    1     1      1
4   -1    1     1      1
5   -1   -1    -1     -1
6    1    1     1      1
7   -1    1     1      1
8   -1    1    -1      1
9   -1    1    -1      1
10  -1    1     1      1
11  -1   -1    -1      1
12  -1    1    -1     -1
13  -1   -1    -1      1
14  -1   -1    -1     -1
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Take a look at `melt` from the `reshape2` package and it should be fairly straight forward.  In general, `ggplot` likes things in "long" format rather than wide.

Comment: i thought of using `ddply` to summarize the data but i cant group it by just one column so i got stuck again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just melt or stack your data.frame:

```
DF <- read.table(text="x1   x2     x3    x4
1   -1    1     1      1
2   -1    1     1     -1
3   -1    1     1      1
4   -1    1     1      1
5   -1   -1    -1     -1
6    1    1     1      1
7   -1    1     1      1
8   -1    1    -1      1
9   -1    1    -1      1
10  -1    1     1      1
11  -1   -1    -1      1
12  -1    1    -1     -1
13  -1   -1    -1      1
14  -1   -1    -1     -1",header=TRUE)

DF.stack <- stack(DF)
```

`geom_bar` uses `stat_bin` by default. It's not necessary to summarize yourself.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF.stack,aes(x=ind,fill=factor(values))) + geom_bar()
```

If you want the numbers, use `table(DF.stack)`.

Comment: Thats amazing. just what i needed. can you hint on how can i control the colors ? i want -1 to be red and 1 to be green ( i'm new to ggplot).

Comment: @haki - `  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))`. I highly recommend reading through the ggplot documentation, it is quite extensive: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/